# Caffe loading LMDB batches very slowly

Tags: linux, database, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

I generated an LMDB database using the SSD-Caffe fork [here](https://github.com/chuanqi305/ssd). I have successfully generated the VOC LMDB trainval/test LMDB directories and am able to train the model.

However, during training, it takes inordinatly long to load data from the LMDB database. For example when profiling using Caffe's `time` function using this command:

`ssdcaffe time --model "jobs/VGGNet/VOC0712/SSD_300x300/train.prototxt" --gpu 0 --iterations 20`

I get that the forward pass takes on average 8.9s, and the backward pass takes on average 0.5s. On a layer-by-layer inspection, the data injestion layer takes the bulk of that time at 8.7s. See below:

```
I1129 10:14:11.094445  8011 caffe.cpp:404]       data   forward: 8660.38 ms.
...
I1129 10:14:11.095383  8011 caffe.cpp:412] Average Forward pass: 8933.31 ms.
I1129 10:14:11.095389  8011 caffe.cpp:414] Average Backward pass: 519.549 ms.
```

If I half the batchsize from 32 to 16, then the data injestion layer time decreases roughly in half:

```
I1129 10:20:07.975527  8093 caffe.cpp:404]       data   forward: 3906.53 ms.
```

This is clearly not the intended speed, and something is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue:

My images were too big. The standard VOC images which the repo used were ~350x500 pixels, whereas my images were 1080x1920. When I downsized my images by 3x (eg 9x less pixels), my data ingestion layer took only 181ms (a 48x speedup over previous time of 8.6s)